# An upgrade from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3 broke my routes, although they should be 1.3 compatible

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-1.3

I`v been upgrading CakePHP from 1.2.10 to 1.3.11 by using "[Migrating from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3)" Guide and i'm aware that i must ensure that my routes are compatible with 1.3.

However my routes don't do anything that's incompatible:

> This is no longer supported as mid-route greedy stars behaved
>   erratically, and complicated route compiling. Outside of these two
>   edge-case features and the above changes the router behaves exactly as
>   it did in 1.2

The other edge case is:

> First path segments using full regular expressions was removed.

### How my routes behave:

- When opening homepage, **doesn't work**, however on 1.2 it sucessfully matched route #1 (solved by Ivo)
- **/lv/products** **doesn't work**. Should have matched #6 using controller "Products" and default action "index" but it thinks that "lv" is controller (ignoring the :lang param)
- **/lv/products/index** works!
- **/lv/products/view/productname** works!

Cake provides errors similar to this error (copied when opening **/lv/products**:

```
Missing Controller
Error: LvController could not be found.
Error: Create the class LvController below in file: app\controllers\lv_controller.php
<?php
class LvController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Lv';
}
?>
```

### My routes:

```
    //Route #1: This route should have worked as a root route, because we have a default for :lang. But now i cannot open up the homepage if i don't define explicit "/" route
    Router::connect("/:lang/",
        array("controller" => "start", "lang" => "lv"),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );

    //#2 This route seems to work ok.
    Router::connect("/admin/:lang/:controller/:action/*",
        array("lang" => "lv", "admin" => true),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );

    // ==============================================================================

    //#3 Routes with static parts - works
    Router::connect("/:lang/info/*",
        array("controller" => "sections", "action" => "view", "lang" => "lv"),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );

    //#4
    Router::connect("/:lang/news",
        array("controller" => "news", "action" => "listall", "lang" => "lv"),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );

    //#5
    Router::connect("/:lang/employees",
        array("controller" => "employees", "action" => "index", "lang" => "lv"),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );

    // ==============================================================================


    //#6 Catch all route. 
    Router::connect("/:lang/:controller/:action/*",
        array("lang" => "lv"),
        array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
    );
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a default root, I would guess that you want `'/'`, or `'/<param>'`

`'/:lang/'` expects something to be there for lang - it's not optional, afaik. Try `'/:lang'` instead.

Comment: thank you, the default route now works. However /lv/products still don't work.

Comment: Ahh, i fixed it by adding explicit route: `Router::connect("/:lang/:controller",
  array("lang" => "lv"),
  array("lang" => "[a-z]{2}")
 );`